# Uncheck all other checkboxes except this one and remove css classes from them

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, checkbox

I have a table rows with checkboxes, when I click the row takes the class 'selected' and the checkbox becomes selected.

```
    $("#emp_grid tbody tr").click(function (e) {
    if (e.target.type == "checkbox") {

        // stop the bubbling to prevent firing the row's click event
        e.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        var $checkbox = $(this).find(':checkbox');
        $checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));
        $(this).filter(':has(:checkbox)').toggleClass('selected');              


    }
});
```

How can I make all the other checkboxes **un-selected** and remove the 'selected' class from rows except the selected one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your current script something like this should work.

```
$("#emp_grid tbody tr").click(function(e) {
    $("#emp_grid tbody tr").removeClass("selected");
    $("#emp_grid :checkbox").not(e.target).removeAttr("checked");
    if (e.target.type == "checkbox") {

        // stop the bubbling to prevent firing the row's click event
        e.stopPropagation();
    } else {

        var $checkbox = $(this).find(':checkbox');
        $checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));
        $(this).filter(':has(:checkbox)').toggleClass('selected');
    }
});
```

[**Code example on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/UYkXS/)

Not sure of the final markup, but it sounds you only want one checkbox selectable?  If that is the case maybe a radio button list would be more appropriate instead of a checkbox list?

**Update**
To allow for toggle of checkbox on row click you can try something like this:

```
$("#emp_grid tbody tr").click(function(e) {
    $("#emp_grid tbody tr").removeClass("selected");
    var $checkbox = $(this).find(':checkbox');
    $("#emp_grid :checkbox").not($checkbox).removeAttr("checked");
    if (e.target.type == "checkbox") {

        // stop the bubbling to prevent firing the row's click event
        e.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        $checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));
        $(this).filter(':has(:checkbox)').toggleClass('selected');
    }
});
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/UYkXS/1/)**

Comment: That's true, normally this is a typical Radio button functionality however my employer wants to do it with Checkboxes anyway.  By the way it didnt help :(

Comment: Strangely it works in your code example on jsfiddle well but not in my page :(  By the way another problem is: Can I make the same functionality on clicking the Checkboxes only as well

Comment: @wallace740, fork the jsfiddle with your markup and I can take a look at what is happening.

Comment: Sorry it is working, my bad. However if it is selected once, there is no un-selecting, at least 1 row stays selected always. Instead of "$("#" + id + " :checkbox").not(e.target).removeAttr("checked");" is it possible for this to be toggle as well?

Comment: @wallace740, see updated fiddle, should take care of the toggle of the checkbox.

Comment: Thx @Mark, the toggle is working fine but the 'selected' css class is not working with Checkboxes(as it works fine with Row selection)

Comment: @Mark  is it possible to leave 1 checkbox always selected? I dont want to toggle the last checkbox **[http://jsfiddle.net/uPqXf/](http://jsfiddle.net/uPqXf/)**